# Can I use Jenkins performance plugin with 'errors only' results file?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

I'm using `Jenkins` to start a `jmeter` performance test that sends thousands request over one hour.

To avoid storing lots of report data for each successful request and send it all over the network I only log errors on my View Results Tree element.

I was planning on using that errors only file to decide whether the test passed or failed.

But by using [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) it reports that 100% of the tests failed (of course, because all of the requests on that file were related to errors).

Is there a way of using this plugin (or any other) to achieve my goal?

Comment: If you save only errors, you have only errors.

What's the actual goal you want to achieve?

Comment: I wish there was a way to make Jenkins Performance Plugin to understand that those 'n' errors does not represent 100% of errors. It seems to be impossible for the reason you just mentioned: I only saved errors.

Comment: There are a few ways you can reduce result file size and still save both successful and failed requests. Have a look at particular info you save per every request (google for jmeter.properties, saveservice) and dave only what you need to. You may also use csv instead of xml.  To save disk space across subsequent runs, you can publish only relevant artifacts as a post build step and clean the workspace with every execution.  Given you have the information you are looking for, how do you want to make the decision to pass or fail the build?